# Prevent GPG from exposing portion of private key

Tags: gnupg

I have three keys;  I'll refer to them as 'foo' `[C]`, 'bar' `[SE]`, and 'baz' `[A]`.  Whenever I run `gpg2 --export-private-subkeys baz!`, it asks for a password, as it should.  However, if I click 'Cancel', it proceeds to print out half of the private key anyway!

Output of `wc` when I don't enter a password:  `29 36 1658`.
Output of `wc` when I *do* enter a password:   `60 67 3717`.

By comparing the output from "no password" to the output from "yes password", I can see that the text is, indeed, identical to the first half of the 'baz' key.

Even stranger, when I run `gpg2 --export-private-subkeys` on 'foo' or 'bar', it *still* prints out half of 'baz' when I decline to enter a password!

Is there any way I can stop it from exposing half of 'baz' when there is no password entered?  Why do you think it would be doing this?

Comment: It turns out that the first halves of 'bar' and 'baz' are identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `--export-secret-subkeys` command, it will export the public part of the key as well. You're seeing the output of that. You can test with the following:

```
gpg2 --export-secret-subkeys > /tmp/cancelled.gpg
gpg2 --export-secret-subkeys > /tmp/not-cancelled.gpg
```

Cancel the passphrase input on the first one, and then try this:

```
export GNUPGHOME=$(mktemp -d)
gpg2 --import /tmp/cancelled.gpg
# the output will mention importing the public key
# you will not be asked for the passphrase
gpg2 --list-secret-keys
# the output will be empty
```

Do the same with the non-cancelled one:

```
export GNUPGHOME=$(mktemp -d)
gpg2 --import /tmp/non-cancelled.gpg
# the output will mention importing the public and secret keys
# you will also need to put in the passphrase to import the key
gpg2 --list-secret-keys
# the output will show the secret key
```

So, when you click "Cancel" only the public key is written out.

Comment: Thanks!  Alright, that makes sense.  And the reason why it was showing the same "public" portion of the private key for 'bar' as 'baz', was because the two of them are actually identical where that part is concerned.